# Difference between "forementioned" and "aforementioned"?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

I am writing a scientific article, and the reviewer has pointed out that I should check the typo "forementioned", which I use several times in the paper. I would like to know, is there any difference between "forementioned" and "aforementioned"? Should I use "aforementioned" instead?

Comment: Closed as off-topic on ELL 2 days ago for lack of research. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/577654/difference-between-forementioned-and-aforementioned/577656#577656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning. However, **formentioned** has fallen out of favor since 1850 or so, and **aforementioned** is the survivor. My browser won't even accept **forementioned** as a correctly spelled word.

**[This Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forementioned%2Caforementioned&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforementioned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caforementioned%3B%2Cc0)** chart illustrates the change. It should be very reliable, as Ngrams are created by references to texts, and the word is almost always restricted to printed texts, especially academic articles.

So the reviewer is right. Use **aforementioned**.